# How let Twig write the HTML output to a file, instead to a browser?

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

I have a Twig template (.html file) that I want to render (replace the tokens with values from my PHP file). Instead of sending the rendered result to a browser, however, I want to write it to a new .html file. I would imagine the solution would also be similar for a Django template.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Everything you need is here [link to official doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html). Else, share some code you tried...

Comment: @YenneInfo I have read the documentation carefully. It's mainly geared into how configure the output towards the browser. Not about where I could 'catch' the HTML-output and write it to a file instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the rendered output assigned to a variable and then do with it what you please.

```
$bob = $this->render('MyBundle:index.html.twig',[
            'foo' => $foo,
            'token' => $token
        ]);
dump($bob->getContent());exit(0);
```

Comment: I never thought of that.. thanks, it seems so simple now.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert it is a symfony function. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Comment: if you don't want the headers to be included in the file, use `renderView` instead of `render`